# regex separate similar strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a file with many lines that starts with a `#lineNumber=` (i.e. `#123=`) and then that reference will appear in another place in the text like `#123` without the =.

I want to add an anchor to the first string and I want to make the reference into a link and write it all out as an html page, but since the reference is a part of the anchor it will replace part of the anchor too.

This will find the "anchor text": `/^(#[0-9]*=)/gm`, and this will find the reference: `/^(#[0-9]*)/gm`. But how can I separate the second expressions to not include part of the first one?

TL;DR:

I want to find all of the numbers in a text that starts with a #, `#123` but exluding the ones that starts witg a # and ends with =, `#123=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(#[0-9]+\b(?!=))
```

This will ensure second does ot include the first part.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/rX1tE6/3

Comment: Aren't those parentheses unbalanced?

Comment: Thanks, but it does not behave as I expected... How can I find only the ones without the = after, and exclude the ones with?

Comment: @vks, I'm not sure why but your regex only found one instance of the pattern. Here is your regex again but in a new version: https://regex101.com/r/yV4qY3/1 I want to find all patterns in the text, but excluding the ones that ends with =. Thanks again for your effort!

Comment: Huh, why didn't I see the ^... That's it anyway, Thank you so much!